# django - using regex to strip and replace a urlfield

Tags: python, regex, django, video, youtube

I want to save url field of videos from youtube, so that I can load it in my site. So far I came up with this in the html:

```
<h3>{{video.title}}</h3>
<object width="425" height="344"><param name="movie" value="{{video.video_url}}"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><param name="allowscriptaccess" value="always"></param><embed src="{{video.video_url}}" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowscriptaccess="always" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="344"></embed></object>
```

But the problem is that it works only in one way. Eg:

url: `http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4lHTj9xFqE`

This will only work if the `watch?` is striped and `=` becomes `/`

So that final url will be somewhat like this

```
http://www.youtube.com/v/e4lHTj9xFqE
```

I was thinking of using regex before it gets saved and replace and strip the url. How do I do to strip the `watch?` and then replace `=` with a `/`? Also is there any better way to load the video in the html? Suggestion from you guys will be most appreciated. Thank you!

**Edit:**

models.py:

```
class Video(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    video_url = models.URLField(max_length=100)

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        new_url = (self.video_url.replace("watch?v=","v/"))
        super(Video, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
        if new_url:
            self.video_url = new_url
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Why regex:

```
string = (r'http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=e4lHTj9xFqE'.replace('watch?','')).replace('=','/')
print string
#http://www.youtube.com/v/e4lHTj9xFqE
```

But if you need [regex](/questions/tagged/regex) here ya go:

```
new_url = re.sub('watch\?v=','v/',self.video_url)
```

## EDIT:

try this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    new_url = re.sub('watch\?v=','v/',self.video_url)
    if new_url:
        self.video_url = new_url
        super(Video, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

and don't modify the html

Comment: Thank you for both the answer! And I did tried it, but I am getting error. I have added my models.py. Will you please have a look at it.

Comment: The regex way too don't replace it.

Answer (score 2):

I would work with a simple [replace](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.replace)

```
video.video_url.replace("watch?v=", "v/")
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I tried it the way you told me, but its not replacing it. Is the problem with my `method`? I have added my models.py please have a look at it.

Comment: You are calling `save` to early. Try doing that *after* you set `self.video_url` to `new_url`. If you save a new instance of a model to the DB that does not mean any changes to this instance will be persisted to the DB automatically afterwards.